# TypeScript Import export and modules

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I am using requirejs+typescript.

I have a compilation error in this Homecontroller.ts script:**"cannt find namespace module**"

```
/// <reference path="../lib/typings/require.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../lib/typings/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="controllers.ts" />


import Controller=module("Controllers");

 class HomeController {

    constructor() {

    }

}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: The error occurs because the import statement is invalid syntax. Please post your code for the `Controllers` module and check out the import syntax definitions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242)

Answer (score 0):

> `import Controller=module("Controllers");`

This code is invalid TypeScript. Perhaps you meant to do `import Controller= require("./controllers");`.

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html